# Does having a URL that contains (and displays) a port can lead to some security risks?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, security, port, url

I have a server that contains Filemaker Server on port 80/443 and a website on port 1111.

By creating a DNS for the website, I have the url https://mydns.xx:1111/.
Showing the port is not really a problem in this case (I do not think I have the choice because I only have one IP address and the customer does not want to pay for a second one server but if you know a solution, I'm still a taker).

My question is: does having a URL that contains (and displays) a port can lead to some security risks?
This site will be used by various users (it is a site that allows
  for example to create an account, to modify his profile, etc).

The server is running on Windows Server 16.

Comment: The web server is exposed to the public on whatever port you configure it to use. I don't see how exposing the port number in the URL changes that from a security perspective. The server is already accessible. A port scanner will detect the port whether or not it's exposed in the URL.

Comment: Additionally, i f you only have 1 ip address then you should look into name-based virtual host or host headers.

Comment: And a proxy, and IPv6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security? No, the risk is the same. All Internet facing hosts will get scanned on all their ports.

Usability problem? Maybe. Some users will only enter `example.com` into their browsers, and give you a blank stare when you say you need some numbers after that.

A network level solution is to get more IP addresses by demanding IPv6 from your provider.

An application level solution is to use proxies, named based virtual hosts, or web server URL rewrite rules.  These allow you to put one web server or proxy in front of multiple things.

Comment: +1 for IPv6 as a solution

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just saw that our server provider can provide us with a second IPv4 address for free. So i will ask for it and i will switch the website on the second IP address, i guess it will work :-)